# How to filter price range for products in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to filter my products list by price specified by user(min and max price).I have two input box for taking price range.'price' is one of the column in my database table.I am getting error as int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'.I have include my template file and small part of views file.

Models.py,

```
class Add_prod(models.Model):
    book = models.CharField("Book Name",max_length=40)
    author = models.CharField("Author",max_length=30)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField("Price")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images',null=True)
    cat = models.ForeignKey(Add_cat,on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.cat)
```

My template file,

```
<p>Price</p>
<input type="text" name="min_price" maxlength="4" size="3" >
to <input type="text" name="max_price" maxlength="4" size="3"> 
<input type="submit" value="Go">
```

views.py,

```
@csrf_protect  
def welcome_user(request): 
    if 'min_price' in request.GET:
        filter_price1 = request.GET.get('min_price')
        filter_price2 = request.GET.get('max_price')
        if filter_price1 =='':
            filter_price1=0
        if filter_price2=='':
            filter_price2=Add_prod.objects.all().aggregate(Max('price'))
        my_products = Add_prod.objects.filter(price__range=(filter_price1,filter_price2))
        context = { "products":my_products}
   return render(request,"welcome-user.html",context)
```

I also tried like this,

```
my_products = Add_prod.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM books_add_prod where price between filter_price1 and filter_price2')
```

Comment: `filter_price1 = request.GET.get('min_price')` `print filter_price1`

Comment: Its printing correctly in unicode number format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this line wrong `filter_price2=Add_prod.objects.all().aggregate(Max('price'))`
Cause aggragate will return a dict

See this docs [Aggragation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet)

Try this：
`my_products=Add_prod.objects.filter(price__range(filter_price1,filter_price2['price_max']))`

Comment: I used dictionary.get() method now both values are of type 'int' but still products are not filtering

Comment: Can I see you models.py ?
And also would try this : `print(Add_prod.objects.filter( price__range(10,11)) )`,  or other number, to see weather it work or not.

Comment: Weird, may i see your models.py ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me, this might not be the optimal way to do it. But it works so anyone from future could give it a try:

```
   <form method="get">
    <input type="text" name="min_price" maxlength="4" size="3" required>         
    to <input type="text" name="max_price" maxlength="4" size="3" required> 
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
    </form>
```

And In your Views:

```
if 'min_price' in request.GET:    
        filter_price1 = request.GET.get('min_price')
        filter_price2 = request.GET.get('max_price')
        if filter_price1 =='':
            filter_price1=0
        products = Products.objects.filter(price__range=(filter_price1,filter_price2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation ([cheatsheet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet)) as follows to determine the maximum `price`:

```
from decimal import Decimal as D
...
price1 = D(request.GET.get('min_price', 0)) 
price2 = D(request.GET.get('max_price', 0))

if not price2:
    price2 = Add_prod.objects.aggregate(Max('price'))['price__max']

my_products = Add_prod.objects.filter(price__range=(price1, price2))
```

On a different note, why do you use `text` inputs for `price` which I assume is a `DecimalField`? What about a number input (or a [django form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/)) in order to make sure that the casts in your view don't raise errors :

```
<input type="number" name="min_price" min="0" step="0.01" >
```

Comment: I explicitly converted them like this,filter_price1 = int(filter_price1)  but still no use all products being shown